# Create empty divs if position id isn't set

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to cycle through a 3x3 grid with the top row being 1, 2, 3, and so on so you can add a picture to one space on the grid and it's stored in a local database. When I'm outputting my data i'm using Razor to grab everything in my list. like so:

```
@foreach (var pref in Model.userPref)
{
    var title = @pref.title.ToLower().Replace(" ", "-");

    <div class="favourite-app" data-position="@pref.position_id" data-appid="@pref.app_id"><a href="@pref.url" class="@title" target="_blank">@pref.title</a></div> 
}
```

Now the issue I'm having is that's only outputting the content in the database, I can't get it to add in the empty divs around the pictures. I've tried to put a for loop around it and count up to 9 and make an if statement however I'm not having any luck with that, it's just outputting 9 of each app.

Comment: use bootstrap grid system

Comment: @rashfmnb I would but the div's don't exist yet. I want to create the div on the fly if there isn't an entry for that spot in the database.

Comment: create two templates one for existing one and one for nonexisting one and then use if(exist){  existing template div }else { non existing template div}

Comment: Hmm, maybe easier to create all the divs ahead of time, then just have javascript set content as needed.